# Pre-processor parsing on C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If we want to use user input to do something in a program, or print a result we need to

```
 #include <iostream>
```

otherwise, `cout` and `cin` will not be acknowledged by the compiler.However the command `#include` is a pre-processor command. And when I was writing my program the following happened. I wrote the following code :

```
#define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a) {cout << “Info: ” << a << endl;}
#include <iostream>
```

And no errors popped up.How is it possible to use `cout` before including `iostream`? Even if I declare the `PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a)` without including  `iostream`, I don't get a compiling error.
Can somebody explain me why this happens?

Comment: `define` is not a function, it will just copy all code and replace wherever you use it.

Comment: `#include <iostream>`, not `#include iostream`.

Comment: You didn't "use" `cout` before it was declared.  All you did was define a macro that contained the text `cout` (and `endl`) that could be used later in the code.

Comment: Imagine I write `void func() {int cout, endl; PRINT_DEBUG_INFO("blah");}`, then there is no problem with `cout` being missing (although there is another problem with trying to use `<<` on a number and a string).

Comment: The preprocessor is just a monkey that goes Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V all over your code before the compiler gets to see it, it doesn't know anything about compiler errors. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't require any C++ declared symbols to be evaluated to do its work.

It's **pure text processing**, so defining a macro like

```
#define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a) {cout << “Info: ” << a << endl;}
```

and expanding it like

```
#include <iostream>

void foo {
  int a = 5;
  PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a);
}
```

will become

```
// All the literal stuff appearing in <iostream>

void foo {
  int a = 5;
  {cout << “Info: ” << a << endl;};
}
```

So there's nothing checked regarding proper C++ syntax during definition or expansion of the macro.

These statements will be processed further by the C++ compiler, which will complain about `cout` isn't declared in the global scope.

To fix this, declare your macro like

```
#define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a) {std::cout << “Info: ” << a << std::endl;}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I totally forgot to do so.Thanks again

Comment: Syntax _is_ checked '_during_ expansion', but not during definition and not _before_ or _until_ expansion. And to be clear: _lexing_ (which is formally separate from syntax, although many people consider them together) _is_ done/checked during definition.

Comment: Nice answer. Just adding that you can always try running only the pre-processor in isolation (using the `-E` switch for GCC) and look at the code that will / would be fed into the compiler. This is a very useful technique when debugging more complicated macros.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I could be wrong, but my understanding was that the preprocessor's lexing was technically separate from the compiler's lexing. After all, they're often implemented as literally separate programs.

Comment: @ruakh: traditionally they were separate although I think that has become less popular, but if so the tokens must remain the same, though only the compiler interprets them as keywords, types, variables, etc; see the phases in 2[lex] in any version (or more cheaply draft) of the C++ standard. This was standardized by the first C standard; before that you could e.g. `#define f(a,b) a/**/b` and use `f(AB,CD)` to get a single token `ABCD` on _some_ implementations, but post-C89 it must be two tokens `AB CD` and to get 'pasting' you must explicitly use `##`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The existence of the token pasting operator `##`, even in a standard that explicitly forbids any other token pasting mechanism, already means that preprocessor tokens and compiler tokens aren't the same thing.

Comment: @ruakh I'm not so sure that discussing these particular details relate to the Q&A here. Consider to discuss that further in a separate chat room please!

Answer (score 3):

You define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO but you don't use it so there is nothing for the compiler to compile or complain about.

Answer (score 2):

You are just defining `PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a)` and not using it. When you actually use it inside your program you will get the error that `cout` is not defined.

When you are not actually using it, the compiler finds no place to substitute the defined constant. When you actually use it, the program gets expanded during compilation and shows you the error.

And moreover there is a bracket in your macro which gets expanded with brackets and may lead to error.

Comment: Can you explain your sentence/paragraph on 'a bracket … expanded with brackets and may lead to error'?  I think the 'expanded with brackets' bit is what's worrying me, but I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest.  The biggest issue with `{…}` macros is that you can't write `if (something) PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(something); else { …do something… }` because the semicolon means the `else` is invalid.  The usual workaround is `#define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO(a) do { … } while (0)` which make it all clean again.